# HTML5 Notifications не запрашивает права (Использую Open Server)

Tags: javascript, html, openserver, уведомления

Кнопка HTML:

```
<button onclick="notifyMe()" value="Notification">Разрешить</button>
```

Код JS:

```
<script>
function notifyMe() {
  // Проверка поддержки браузером уведомлений
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  // Проверка разрешения на отправку уведомлений
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // Если разрешено, то создаём уведомление
    var notification = new Notification ("Проверка",{
      tag : "ache-mail",
      body : "Тело уведомления",
      icon : "/assets/images/favicon.ico"
    });
  }

  // В противном случае, запрашиваем разрешение
  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      // Если пользователь разрешил, то создаём уведомление
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      }
    });
  }

  // В конечном счёте, если пользователь отказался от получения
  // уведомлений, то стоит уважать его выбор и не беспокоить его
  // по этому поводу.
  console.log('Результат запроса прав:', Notification.permission);
}
</script>
```

Запрос на получение прав не приходит, как не пытался, пробовал запрашивать напрямую, без условий, разницы никакой.
После нажатия в логе отображается: **Результат запроса прав: denied**.
Использую Open Server и google chrome (Версия 103.0.5060.114)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Как бесполезно потратить два дня]

Пожалуйста, научите меня читать... Я потратил на это два дня( Эта функция доступна только с сертификатом SSL, который у меня отсутствовал...

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]